# Movie where a group go to a cabin with an evil spirit, once the spirit is killed it moves into the body of the person who killed it

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, ghost

I remember watching a movie where a group of people go to a house that sits alone in the woods, for a vacation or something.

The thing is, there's this evil, possessed person inside a locked door. Somehow he comes out and he tries to kill the people that are there on vacation. Once a person shoots and kills the possessed person, the evil spirit goes inside the person who killed it.

The ending of the movie was that a person's loved one gets possessed, so he locks her up in the room and he starts to live in that house.

It is a very similar movie to *Don't Kill It*. But I watched this like maybe in 2013-2015. I think *Don't Kill It* is a copy of it with one difference: that in *Don't Kill It*... there's a clear hunter who hunts all... where in the movie which I'm looking for they'll only have a vague idea on how to kill it until the end.

Even in the end, the protagonist locks up the possessed one in the room and lives in the house until:

1. Maybe he gets possessed
2. Kill the possessed in the room and lock himself up inside the room without getting out

Comment: Sounds a bit like http://collider.com/dont-kill-it-review/#images

Comment: Nope. Its not Dot kill it. Older than that

Comment: Sounds extremely similar to The Evil Dead

Comment: No. Its like the movie *Don't kill it*. You kill it and it gets inside of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be [**The Damned (AKA *Gallows Hill***)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2387408/), which does have the same concept as *'Don't Kill It'* but preceded it (it's from 2013).

> After a family is involved in an accident, they take refuge in a secluded inn where they free a girl locked in a basement without knowing she's an ancient evil spirit.

It's basically a demon-witch that possesses whoever killed the previous person she possessed. And it ends like you described: With a girl killing the last person and then getting possessed, and her dad locking her up and living with her, waiting for her to die (which is ironically how all of this started). Here's the trailer, and you can see his imprisoned daughter's eye right at the end: